# Jenkins why need both pr-merge and branch build for checks

Tags: jenkins, cicd

In our github pr and Jenkins pipeline after we commit code and open a pull request, two checks have to pass, one for pr merge and one for branch. Why do we need two checks? For github, the branch is required to be uptodate with main and the pipeline build passes, it should be sufficient, what would the pr-merge check do?

I could supply more stages for each build if it helps answering the questions, but for the large part they are similar pipelines: checkout, linter, unit test, functional test, integration test, docker publish

```
Some checks haven’t completed yet
2 pending checks
continuous-integration/jenkins/branch 
continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge
```